# assign multiple const to the same value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is something like this possible? I have tried using `let` with no success after some research.

```
const [container, item, columnLeft, columnRight] = document.createElement('div');
```

or

```
let [container, item, columnLeft, columnRight] = document.createElement('div');
```

Comment: That only works if document.createElement returns an array of four (or more) items.  It would assign a variable to each element in that array, named as you have.

Comment: Tha should not work, `.createElement()` returns object not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing on the right has to match the destructuring thing on the left, in your case the thing on the left is looking for an array with at least four elements, so:

```
const [container, item, columnLeft, columnRight] = [
  document.createElement("div"),
  document.createElement("div"),
  document.createElement("div"),
  document.createElement("div")
];
```

or, make a temporary array and use its map method to produce the array of divs

```
const [container, item, columnLeft, columnRight] = [1,2,3,4].map(() => document.createElement("div"));
```

Comment: as a goof: `const [container, item, columnLeft, columnRight] = new Array(4).fill(() => document.createElement("div"))` (the thing i'm working on required a number of extra items so just easier to write `Array(10)` over `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` at that point)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x, y, z;
x = y = z = 100;
console.log(x,y,z)
```

Comment: I already tried that with no success unfortunately `const container = item = columnLeft = columnRight = document.createElement('div');`

Comment: Maybe take off const. I noticed when I tried to change x I couldn't but I could change y and z, so I suspect you have to use let

Comment: Same result using let

Comment: @SteveTomlin You suspect correctly. Const variables can only be assigned a variable when declaring it. Works: `const a = 1;`, throws an error: `const a; a=1`. This is by design.